# Fast forwarding Flash Video

Tags: flash, video, performance, playback

Is it possible to use Actionscript to speed up (or slow down) a video playing? Say, having it play at twice the normal speed? If possible, can you also make it that the sound does not get all squeaky? Some Videoplayers can do that, I was wondering if it is possible to do in Flash.

Comment: There's a description of how to do this on [David Stiller's Blog](http://www.quip.net/blog/2007/flash/actionscript-20/how-to-fast-forward-rewind-video). I don't know how the sound is affected.