# Change video playback rate dynamically in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, dynamic, frame-rate

I'm looking for a way to allow a Flash Video to change speed smoothly, from slower to faster than original framerate. It only needs to work on a Windows PC, and the latest version of Flash 10.2 with Stage Video is available.

Comment: possible duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078379/fast-forwarding-flash-video

Answer (score 0):

Flash Media Server provides a 'trick play' mode that facilitates some of those features. 
Check out NetStream.step() and have a look at these links:

http://aspexamples.adobe.com/flash/streamreconnect.html

http://blogs.adobe.com/actionscriptdocs/2010/06/flash_media_server_stream_reco.html